# Highlight selected text in webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I am new to webview in android. I am developing app in which i want to mark selected text in webview.

[image: image from tab]

Here i want to remove right-hand side menus and change text of Done menu and on click on done i want to mark text with color(Highlight text) in webview.

Can anyone have any idea?

Please reply. Waiting for valuable reply.

Comment: How do you highlight multiple paragraphs? In my case, when i highlight text within same paragraph works fine but when i try to highlight text from different paragraphs highlight doesn't work properly. It increases size of paragraph by adding spacing in between selected text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to take control of the selection contextual action bar. But you can prevent it from showing and replace it with your own version. First, create a HighlightWebView class that extends WebView, and include this override:

```
@Override
public android.view.ActionMode startActionMode(android.view.ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    // this will start a new, custom Contextual Action Mode, in which you can control
    // the menu options available.
    highlightActivity.startActionMode(highlighActionModeCallback);

    // this is to prevent the native text selection ActionMode
    return null;
}
```

You'll need to create the HighlightActionModeCallback class as well. Here is a very basic version of a class that implements ActionMode.Callback:

```
public class HighlightActionModeCallBack implements ActionMode.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.highlight_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

You also want to google "contextual action mode" and/or "contextual action bar" for additional information.

Comment: Hi Mike, Its working but swipe event conflict this functionality. Do you have any solution on this?

Comment: @mikejonesguy  would you please suggest me some tutorial to  highlight text permanently in WebView after click done button in CAB.